# XCode 3.2 version: now I can't compile

Tags: iphone

I have this IPhone app underway that was working fine, then I installed OS 10.6 and the shiny new XCode.

It's not compiling, instead coming up with the single error,

```
"There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos3.0'"
```

I can't find such a file or folder on my hard drive.

What's broke, and how do I fix it?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download (or install) the [new Snow Leopard specific Xcode](https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/205/wo/dg5laHPPA3Bo3vC19gJp2Ooe5KP/0.0.17.2.1.3.0.1.2.1.1.0). Snow Leopard should also come with Xcode on its installation disc.

Once you have done that, you have to go back to the iPhone download center and download/install the Snow Leopard specific iPhone development toolset for Xcode.

Comment: We both seem to have read over "I installed OS 10.6 and the shiny new XCode." heh

Answer (score 5):

That's because iphoneos3.0 old and you probably have iphoneos3.1.3 or ios4. You need to go to Project -> Edit Project Settings -> General and change the Base SDK to iphone device 3.0 or 4.0. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your target is setup correctly and you select the right active config.

If you have done that then this might help you out:

> You don't say which version of the SDK
>   you installed. If you installed SDK
>   version 3.2 for snow leopard, then you
>   also need to download and install
>   iPhone OS 3.1 SDK add-on installer for
>   Xcode 3.2 on Snow Leopard. The version
>   3.2 provided on the snow leopard CD or download does not include the iPhone
>   files that you need.

http://forums.oreilly.com/content/Inside-iPhone/5024/Help-With-Samble/

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial for that process: [Reconfiguring Xcode projects after iPhone SDK update](http://www.thecodewar.com/?p=168).